# The operation $\langle a, b\rangle = \{\{∅, a\}, \{\{∅\}, b\}\}$ creates distinct sets from distinct pairs $(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand the variant where $\langle a, b\rangle = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$, but I'm having trouble with the title problem.

My strategy was to prove that $a = b = c = d$, however I ran into a problem in the following way:

In the first case we have $\langle a, b\rangle = \langle a, a\rangle$, thus

$$\langle a, b\rangle = \langle a, a\rangle = \{\{∅, a\}, \{\{∅\}, a\}\}$$

However, $∅ ≠ \{∅\}$.

Hence, $\{∅, a\} ≠ \{\{∅\}, a\}$ and $a ≠ a$.

Is what I've come up with valid? If not, how do I circumvent the fact that $∅ ≠ \{∅\}$?

EDIT: Where I said my strategy is to prove a = b = c = d, I meant that it was my strategy for the case where a = b.

Comment: Please note: $\langle a,b\rangle$, not $<a,b>$  And there's not need to put curly braces in thing like $\{a,b,c\}$ _outside_ the MathJax code.  I've cleaned it up. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say $0$ instead of $\emptyset$ and $1$ instead of $\{\emptyset\}$.  We know that $0 \neq 1$.

If $(a,b)=(c,d)$ (using normal parentheses because they're easier to type) that means $\{\{0,a\},\{1,b\}\}
=\{\{0,c\},\{1,d\}\}$ by definition.

If $a \neq 1$, then there's only one set on the left side containing the element $1$, so there can only be one on the right side containing $1$ which means $c\neq 1$.  This also implies that the two sets containing $1$ must be equal, i.e. $\{1,b\}=\{1,d\}$ and thus $b=d$ (no matter whether $b=1$ or not).  Likewise, the two sets not containing $1$ must be equal and thus $a=c$.

If $a = 1$, then $(a,b)=\{\{0,1\},\{1,b\}\}$, so either $c=1$ or $d=0$.  If $c=1$, then $a=c$ and $(c,d)=\{\{0,1\},\{1,d\}\}$ which obviously implies $b=d$.  If $d=0$, then $(c,d)=\{\{0,c\},\{1,0\}\}$ and so $\{1,b\}=\{0,c\}$, i.e. $b=0=d$ and $c=1=a$.